# Filter JSON array by values included in two arrays (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, filter, lodash

I'm writing a JSON array filter function based on multiple criteria.
The filter depends on two arrays:
1. The first one contains values that have to be part of searched JSON, and
2. the second contains values that are optional.

I mean to return only the array entries that contain ALL the values from the `obligatory` array and at least one item from the `optional` array.

Here's my attempt:

```
const searchKeys = ['varWord', 'varTrans', 'varSpec'],
  obligatory = ['trip', 'pret'],
  optional = ['greet', 'lco', 'toto', 'bene'];

function filterByUpdate(obligatory, optional, file) {
  return _.filter(file, item => {
    return _.some(optional, opt => {
      return _.every(obligatory, oblg => {
        return _.some(item, value => {
          return _.some(searchKeys, n => item[n].toLowerCase().includes(oblg.toLowerCase())) &&
            searchKeys.some(n => item[n].toLowerCase().includes(opt.toLowerCase()))
        })
      });
    });
  });
}
```

The code above should only preserve the first entry from the following data array:

```
[{
  "varSpec": "trip",
  "varTrans": "pret",
  "varWord": "greet",
  "stringPol": "group",
  "stringDva": "groupGend",
  "stringGit": "/tax",
}, {
  "varSpec": "trip",
  "varTrans": "pret",
  "varWord": "friend",
  "stringPol": "N",
  "stringDva": "N",
  "stringGit": "N",
}, {
  "varSpec": "group1",
  "varTrans": "grp1",
  "varWord": "ageGroup1",
  "stringPol": "N",
  "stringDva": "N",
  "stringGit": "N",
}]
```

Comment: searchKeys is an array of JSON Keys, that contain searched values.

Comment: Seems to be working fine. What output you want. It is returning varSpec: "trip"
varTrans: "pret"
varWord: "greet"
stringPol: "group"
stringDva: "groupGend"
stringGit: "/tax"

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/k578p37j03

Comment: ooh yes you are right! thank you for your time, my problem was in different part of my code.

Answer (score 2):

You could go for this pretty simple algorithm:

```
const { flow, intersection, pick } = require('lodash/fp');

data.filter(
  flow(
    pick(searchKeys),
    entry => intersection(Object.values(entry)),
    intersectWith => intersectWith(obligatory).length === obligatory.length &&
                     intersectWith(optional).length >= 1
  )
);
```

It basically boils down to checking for the **intersection** between, on the first hand, the relevant values (identified by `searchKeys`) in each entry of your dataset (`data`), and on the other:

1. the `obligatory` array of values: the intersection must be of `obligatory.length` length.
   *i.e.*: it contains **all** the items from the `obligatory` collection
2. the `optional` array of values: the intersection array's length must be `>= 1`.
   *i.e.*: it contains **at least 1** item from the `optional` collection

Here's a link to a [working repl](https://repl.it/@ccjmne/StackOverflow-52467989).

Comment: thank you man, really appreciate your help and provided example. Gonna try it.